# Vue js - Define prop as a specific type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building a vuejs component which accepts a prop by the name of **idFieldType**

Now I want this prop to accept only a **Number Type** or a **String Type**

So I wrote it as follows

```
idFieldType: {
    Type: Function,
    default: function() {
        return Number;
    },
    validator: function() {
         if(value == String || value == Number) {
               return true;
         }

         return false;    
    }
}
```

I also tried replacing the type to Object.

My question is how can I write a prop that accepts only specific types ?

Comment: you can. try typeOf

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question correctly, but if you want one prop to be either Number or String, why not use `my-prop: [String, Number]`?

Comment: cos I don't want the value to be a string or number, I want the value to be the Type String or Number :)

Comment: It seems Narek-T answered your question, yet you didn't pick it as the top answer.

Answer (score 14):

Vue.JS has built in props validation, you can set type, required or not, default value...
For example:

```
Vue.component('example', {
  props: {
    // basic type check (`null` means accept any type)
    propA: Number,
    // multiple possible types
    propB: [String, Number],
    // a required string
    propC: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    // a number with default value
    propD: {
      type: Number,
      default: 100
    },
    // object/array defaults should be returned from a
    // factory function
    propE: {
      type: Object,
      default: function () {
        return { message: 'hello' }
      }
    },
    // custom validator function
    propF: {
      validator: function (value) {
        return value > 10
      }
    }
  }
})
```

note, that Vue.js also accepts multiple possible types `propB: [String, Number],`, that's what you need.
And you can read more about that in [official wiki](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution..

```
idFieldType: {
                type: Function,
                default: Number,
                validator: function (value) {
                    if (value() == String || value() == Number) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
```

The problem was that when specifying type as Function the default expects a function, I was returning a function returning a function :)

Comment: if you call the function in the validator you should make sure the function is idempotent as you may end up calling it 2 times even before you use it.

Comment: Vue.js doc for prop validation  at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation shows `default` attribute holds a value, not a type. Then how could you use `default: Number` ?